# Issue in navigating to desired screen on clicking a notification when Flutter app is terminated

Tags: android, ios, flutter

**Scenario**

I have a Flutter app with 3 screens:

1. SplashScreen (home of Material App)
2. SecondScreen
3. ThirdScreen

**Requirements**

1. When the app starts the SplashScreen loads and after 3 seconds it navigates to the SecondScreen.
2. When the app is terminated and the user clicks on the notification, he should be taken to the ThirdScreen.

**Problem**

When the notification is clicked while the app is terminated, the app launches and takes the user to the SecondScreen and stops there. It doesn't navigate to the ThirdScreen.

However, if I disable the navigation from the SplashScreen to SecondScreen, I am able to reach the ThirdScreen upon clicking on the notification when the app is terminated. Unfortunately, it is a mandatory requirement for my app to take the user from SplashScreen to SecondScreen automatically after 3 seconds.

**Code**

The following code is responsible for navigating to the ThirdScreen when the notification is clicked on.

```
navigatorKey.currentState
          ?.push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ThirdScreen()));
```

**Request**

I would like to know if this is a shortcoming on Flutter's part which prevents navigation to desired screen if the home screen of the app has a Navigation of its own. All tutorials that I have watched, only show us how to navigate to a desired screen when notification is clicked on while app is terminated, but in all these tutorials there is no implementation of a SplashScreen like I do.

Is there a solution or workaround to this?

**EDIT**

**Code for navigation in SplashScreen**

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    navigate();
  }

  Future<void> navigate() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
    if (context.mounted) {
      Navigator.push(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondScreen()));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Notifications")),
      body: // Widgets
  }
```

Comment: Please include the code you use where the splash screen routes to the second screen.  I suspect that that code might be able to be modified to detect that the app was started with a notification route specified and not do the routing it normally does after 3 seconds.

Comment: @JohnWeidner I have included the code where navigation in SplashScreen is called.

Comment: Are you using the flutter_local_notifications package for your notification?  It has a getNotificationAppLaunchDetails() method that could be helpful in determining if your HomePage should navigate to the SecondScreen or not.

Comment: @JohnWeidner I am using awesome_notifications since I need to display buttons to Accept or Reject a VoIP call.

Comment: I haven't used awesome_notifications, but their page at https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications/example shows using a getInitialNotificationAction method.  Maybe that can be used to determine if the app was started from a notification or not.

Comment: @JohnWeidner I have included the navigation in the `getInitialNotificationAction` itself, unfortunately it only works when the HomeScreen doesn't have an automatic navigation of its own.

Comment: I'd suggest making a minimal application that demonstrates the problem and asking for advice on the awesome notifications github - https://github.com/rafaelsetragni/awesome_notifications/issues

Comment: @JohnWeidner I have tweaked the code in `getInitialNotificationAction`. I am now taken to the ThirdScreen as desired, however, the HomeScreen still remains in the stack and I'm taken back to the SecondScreen since the initState() in HomeScreen keeps running. I have used `navigatorKey.currentState?.pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ThirdScreen()),
        (route) => false));` and yet the app takes me back to SecondScreen. Do you know of a way to remove the HomeScreen and it's navigation to SecondScreen call?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254802/discussion-between-john-weidner-and-ayan-dasgupta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a method that determines if the app was started by a notification or not.  For example:

```
Future<bool> getInitNotif() async {
    ReceivedAction? receivedAction = await AwesomeNotifications().getInitialNotificationAction(removeFromActionEvents: true);
    if (receivedAction?.buttonKeyPressed == 'ACCEPT') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then in your main method you could do something like:

```
bool acceptedNotification = await getInitNotif();
runApp(MainApp(acceptedNotification ? const ThirdScreen() : const HomePage()));
```

Where you modified the MainApp to be like:

```
class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
    const MainApp(this.startPage, {super.key});
    final Widget startPage;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            home: startPage,
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and solution. Using your approach I am able to achieve what I was looking for.